# How to implement conditional unique constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, unique-constraint

I have a table that needs a unique constraint on 3 columns, but, if the "date" column in for that insert transaction is a newer date than the current record's date, then I want to ***update*** that record (so the unique constraint is still true for the table).

[Postgres has the concept of deferrable constraints](https://emmer.dev/blog/deferrable-constraints-in-postgresql/), MySQL does not.

I do want to implement it with the SQL object tools available, though.

Here is my table DDL with column names obfuscated:

```
CREATE TABLE `apixio_results_test_sefath` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `insert_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rule` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `another_column` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `another_column1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `insert_date_index` (`insert_date`),
  KEY `number` (`number`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=627393 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and here is the unique constraint statement

```
Alter Table dbname.table add unique constraint my_unique_constraint (number, item_id, rule);
```

but I can not add a condition here in this constraint *(unless there is a way I'm not aware of?)*
The logic I need to run before inserts are blocked by the constraint is to check if the three values: number, item_id, and rule are unique in the table, and if they aren't, then I want to compare the existing record's insert_date with the insert_date from the transaction, and only keep the record with the newest insert_date.

This could be achieved with a trigger I suppose, although I've heard triggers are only to be used if really needed. And on every insert, this trigger would be quite computationally taxing on the DB. Any advice? Any other sql tricks I can use? Or anything to help point me to how to make this trigger?

I tried the unique constraint statement

```
Alter Table dbname.table add unique constraint my_unique_constraint (number, item_id, rule);
```

But it will never update with the newer insert_date.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an insert statement like:

```
insert into apixio_results_test_sefath (number, item_id, rule, insert_date, another_column, another_column1)
values (?,?,?,?,?,?)
on duplicate key update
    another_column=if(insert_date>values(insert_date),another_column,values(another_column),
    another_column1=if(insert_date>values(insert_date),another_column1,values(another_column1),
    insert_date=greatest(insert_date,values(insert_date)
```

for each column besides the unique ones and insert_date, testing to see if the existing insert_date is greater than the value supplied with the insert and conditionally using the existing value or new value for the other column based on that, and ending with updating insert_date only if it is now greater.

mysql 8 has an alternate syntax it prefers to using the values function, but the values function still works.

If you want this to happen automatically for all inserts, you would need to use a trigger.

Comment: i can only manage DB changes, can't change the application code unfortunately. so can't change how to ORM behaves (if it even uses an orm) and effect the insert statements